# I get so confused in possessive pronouns

Tags: pronouns, possessives

Can you please correct these sentences.

1.Can I click a picture of yours.

2.Do you know the email address of John's?

3.I think of both of yours betterment.

4.You are a friend of John's.

Answer (score 2):

1. It's correct, but probably needs a question mark.
2. "Do you know John's email address" or "Do you know the email address of John?"
3. I'd probably go for "I think of the betterment of both of you."
4. "You are a friend of John." No need for a possessive. You could also say "You are John's friend."

Comment: I think it's important to note why.  The possessive is indicated by the word "of" in these cases.  Adding the "'s" to the end makes it redundant.  Logically equivalent to:  "Do you know the email address of John of John."